# What are my options for limiting the bandwidth to Zoom, Teams, etc so that I can pretend I have a bad connection?

Tags: networking, microsoft-teams, zoom-meeting

I have found things like NetLimiter, but they are paid.

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but had to upvote for the audacity!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lag switch that will cut the connection to your computer for a smidge of a second.  It’s relatively cheap if you have a Ethernet cord lying around.  There are multiple resources on it, but the theory is, you will lag out and down bump your resolution and audio quality severely.  It will look like your internet sucks.  Most people use them for multiplayer game cheating but in theory, it should work.